# Which permissions are required to view Windows Event Logs in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, ssms

I'm trying to figure out which permissions are required to be able to view the **Windows Event Logs** via SSMS.

The SSMS Log File Viewer, where you typically view the **SQL Server Errorlog**, also has the ability to show the **Windows Event Logs** via a "Windows NT" checkbox & subtree (pictured below). Being a *SQL Server sysadmin* and *Windows Administrator* this shows up just fine for me.

- Is there a way to give other users the ability to view the Windows Event Logs within SSMS, **without** giving them SQL SysAdmin and Windows Admin level permissions?

I've tried the **Event Log Readers** local security group in Windows, but that doesn't appear to work.

[image: screenshot of SSMS Log File Viewer, showing Window's Event Logs subtree]

Comment: @AliRazeghi connecting via AD

Comment: If you're doing AD auth does your local user have access to the event viewer log?  Can you directly connect, open up SSMS, and see the logs or go to eventvwr.msc from run?

Comment: @AliRazeghi actually I can (and so can others too.) That's what's weird, I'm not sure what is different between viewing the log through Event Viewer and SSMS.

Comment: I think this post has what you're looking for - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82145/view-permission-to-sql-server-logs-on-ssms-gui

Comment: Actually, Scott's link is for adding **SQL Server Log** viewing permissions to SSMS, not the requested **Windows Logs** viewing ones...

Answer (score 2):

The two groups highlighted in the attached image (`Administrators` and `Event Log Readers`) will allow a user, or a member of a group, who is given access to either of these two local groups the ability to view the windows event log. Of course, as long as they are logged on via an AD account.

[image]