# Is there any option to enable Window NT logs in SQL Server Logs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, windows, sql-server-2019

I'm trying to view SQL Server logs on a specific server and is missing Windows NT section in same.

Though other server are showing that section.

In the screenshot shared below, I highlighted section that I'm not getting for one of the SQL Server instances.

**Question**

- Is there any configuration or any required steps, for enabling **Windows NT** section in SQL Server Logs?

Server details with the issues:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   
Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Server details having no issue or the screen server details

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU11-GDR) (KB4535706) - 13.0.5622.0 (X64)   Dec 15 2019 08:03:11   
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

[image]

Comment: Why have you tagged [tag:sql-server-2012] when the versions you mention are 2019 and 2016 (both of which are over a year out of date)?

Comment: Perhaps permissions or remote management issues. Try running compmgmt.msc and connecting to the remote server to see if you can use view the Windows logs via EventViewer.

Comment: The add to my above comment, the latest version of SQL Server 2016 is SP2-CU15, which came out on 2020-09-28. For SQL Server 2019, There's been **8** CU's since RTM, the last of which came out on 2020-10-01.

Comment: To follow up on Dan's comment -- are you using the same credentials to authenticate to each instance? Do you get the same behavior if you run SSMS locally on the "problem" server?

Answer (score 0):

I think this has the answer you are looking for. [See this link to different same question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/148583/which-permissions-are-required-to-view-windows-event-logs-in-ssms) Looks like a user needs membership in the Event Log Readers group or the local Administrators group.